# What does this RDF statment mean: "A class may be a member of its own class extension and may be an instance of itself."?

Tags: rdf, rdfs

Can anybody please explain this statement from RDF Schema 1.1 documentation with an intuitive example?

> A class may be a member of its own class extension and may be an instance of itself.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of examples in the RDFS vocabulary:

```
rdfs:Class  rdf:type  rdfs:Class .
rdfs:Resource  rdf:type  rdfs:Resource .
```

This is because `rdfs:Class` is the class of all classes (so it is a `rdfs:Class`) and `rdfs:Resource` is a resource because everything is a resource in RDF, including the class of all resources.

In addition to these two standard examples, any RDFS vocabulary can define classes that are instances of themselves.

```
my:classOfStuff  rdf:type  my:classOfStuff .
```